# interactive legend with d3.js hover

Tags: javascript

I have been trying to interact with my graph with the legend that I created but I
can't find a way that work. The point is my legend must do 2 things:

1. the text must refer to a url (already done)
2. the color must make it possible to visualize the corresponding part of the graph and gray out the other links and nodes of different colors (this is just my concern)

Here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ewuxfn65/

```js
< script type = "text/javascript" >


  var fileName = ReadCookie("fileName");
//console.log(fileName);

var h1 = document.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0];
h1.innerHTML = "Graph " + fileName + " Visualiser";


//-----------------Legend and color-----------------

tabC = [];
tabL = [];

tab = ["#b87188", "#4a9bda", "#eb7dab", "#f6a602", "#cab3fe", "#ddb8bb", "#107959", "#885973", "#5e858e", "#b15bad", "#e107a7", "#2f9dad", "#4b9e83", "#b992dc", "#6bb0cb", "#bdb363", "#ccd6e4", "#a3ee94", "#9ef718", "#fbe1d9", "#a428a5", "#93514c", "#487434", "#e8f1b6", "#d00938", "#fb50e1", "#fa85e1", "#7cd40a", "#f1ade1", "#b1485d", "#7f76d6", "#d186b3", "#90c25e", "#b8c813", "#a8c9de", "#7d30fe", "#815f2d", "#737f3b", "#c84486", "#946cfe", "#e55432", "#a88674", "#c17a47", "#b98b91", "#fc4bb3", "#da7f5f", "#df920b", "#b7bbba", "#99e6d9", ];

var str = "";
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(tab);
var sequentialScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(tab);


d3.tsv("Output/" + fileName + "_Prefixes.txt", function(data) { //KITION_Prefixes.txt  "Data/KITION_Prefixes.txt"

  data.forEach(function(d) {
    str = JSON.stringify(d);
    words = str.split(';');
    //For color:
    word = words[0].substring(11, words[0].length - 1);
    newWord = word.trim(); //No space on both sides


    if (newWord != "" && !tabC.includes(newWord)) {
      tabC.push(newWord);
    }

    end = tabC.length;
    color = d3.scaleOrdinal(tab.slice(0, end)); //scaleOrdinal(d3.schemePiYG[11]);


    //For legend:
    wordL = words[0].substring(11, words[0].length) + " " + words[1].substring(0, words[1].length - 2);
    //  console.log(wordL);

    if (wordL != "" && !tabL.includes(wordL)) {
      tabL.push(wordL);
    }

  })

  color.domain(tabC);

  sequentialScale = d3.scaleOrdinal(tab.slice(0, end))
    .domain(tabL);


  svg
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "legendSequential")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width - 60) + "," + (height - 650) + ")")
    .style("font-family", " 'Georgia', Times, serif")
    .style("font-size", "14px");


  var legendSequential = d3.legendColor()
    .cells(15)
    .orient("vertical")
    .title("Prefix by:")
    .titleWidth(100)
    .scale(sequentialScale)

    .on('cellclick', function(d, i) {
      // alert(d.trim().split(" ")[1]);
      window.open(d.trim().split(" ")[1]);
    })
    .on('cellover', function(d, i) {
      //svg.select("rect.color-"+ words[i].substring(1)).style("stroke","black");
      d3.select(this).select("text").style("stroke", "red");

    })
    .on('cellout', function(d, i) {
      //svg.select("rect.color-" + words[i].substring(1)).style("stroke","none");
      d3.select(this).select("text").style("stroke", "none");

    })

  svg.select(".legendSequential")
    .call(legendSequential)


});





//------------------------End color-------------------------



var tooltip = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);

var info = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "info")
  //  .style("overflow", "scroll")
  .style("opacity", 0);

var svg = d3.select("svg"),
  width = +svg.attr("width"),
  height = +svg.attr("height"),
  node,
  link;


//var legend = svg.select(".svg").attr("class",function (d){
//return "link" + "Node" + "color-"+ sequentialScale(d.value).substring(1);
//});




svg.append('defs').append('marker')
  .attrs({
    'id': 'arrowhead',
    'viewBox': '-0 -5 10 10',
    'refX': 16, //13
    'refY': 0,
    'orient': 'auto',
    'markerWidth': 22,
    'markerHeight': 7,
    'xoverflow': 'visible'
  })
  .append('svg:path')
  .attr('d', 'M 0,-5 L 10 ,0 L 0,5')
  .attr('fill', '#c1c1c1')
  .style('stroke', 'none');




var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force('link', d3.forceLink().id(d => d.id) /*.strength(0.0025)*/ .distance(120))
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-60))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))



d3.json("Output/" + fileName + "_Profile.json", function(error, graph) {
  if (error) throw error;

  update(graph.links, graph.nodes);

})


function update(links, nodes) {


  //-----------------Grouping:-------------------------------------------------
  var linkGroup = {};
  //Counting and grouping of connections, regardless of the direction of the connection, as long as they belong to the same two entities
  var linkmap = {}
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var key = links[i].source < links[i].target ? links[i].source + ':' + links[i].target : links[i].target + ':' + links[i].source;
    if (!linkmap.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      linkmap[key] = 0;
    }
    linkmap[key] += 1;
    if (!linkGroup.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      linkGroup[key] = [];
    }
    linkGroup[key].push(links[i]);
  }

  //Assign the size attribute to each connection line and number each group of connections
  for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    var key = links[i].source < links[i].target ? links[i].source + ':' + links[i].target : links[i].target + ':' + links[i].source;
    links[i].size = linkmap[key];
    //Numbering of relationships in the same group
    var group = linkGroup[key];
    var keyPair = key.split(':');
    var type = 'noself'; //Indicate whether the group of relationships refers to two different entities or the same entity
    if (keyPair[0] == keyPair[1]) {
      type = 'self';
    }
    //Assigning numbers to nodes
    setLinkNumber(group, type);
  }

  //-----------------End Grouping:-------------------------------------------------

  //links:
  link = svg.selectAll(".link")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr('marker-end', 'url(#arrowhead)')



  /* link.append("title")
       .text(function (d) {return d.type + d.stat;})*/

  edgepaths = svg.selectAll(".edgepath")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append('path')
    .attrs({
      'class': 'edgepath',
      'fill-opacity': 0,
      'stroke-opacity': 0,
      'id': function(d, i) {
        return 'edgepath' + i
      }
    })
    .style("pointer-events", "none");

  edgelabels = svg.selectAll(".edgelabel")
    .data(links)
    .enter()
    .append('text')
    .style("pointer-events", "none")


    .attrs({
      'class': 'edgelabel',
      'id': function(d, i) {
        return 'edgelabel' + i
      },
      'font-size': 15,
    });

  edgelabels.append('textPath')
    .attr('xlink:href', function(d, i) {
      return '#edgepath' + i
    })
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .style("pointer-events", "none")
    .attr("startOffset", "50%")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.value + "\n" + "(" + d.stat + ")"
    });




  link
    .style("stroke", function(d, i) {
      return color(d.prefix);
    })
    .on('mouseover.tooltip', function(d) {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", .8);

      var trStr1 = "";
      var trStr2 = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < d.subset_of_source.length; i++) {
        trStr1 += "<tr><td>" + d.subset_of_source[i] + "</td></tr>";
      }

      for (var j = 0; j < d.subset_of_target.length; j++) {
        trStr2 += "<tr><td>" + d.subset_of_target[j] + "</td></tr>";
      }

      tooltip.html(
          "<table cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=500 border=0><tr><td align=center width=50% valign=top>" +
          "<table width=100% border=1 bordercolordark=white bordercolorlight=black cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>" +
          "<tr>" + "<th>Subset of source</th></tr>" +
          trStr1 +
          "</table></td>" +
          "<td valign=top>" +
          "<table width=100% border=1 bordercolordark=white bordercolorlight=red cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>" +
          "<tr>" + "<th>Subset of target</th></tr>" +
          trStr2 +
          "</table>" +
          "</td></tr></table>")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on("mouseout.tooltip", function() {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    })
    .on('mouseout.fade', fade(2))
    .on("mousemove", function() {
      tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on("click.info", function(d) {
      info.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1);

      var trStr1 = "";
      var trStr2 = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < d.subset_of_source.length; i++) {
        trStr1 += d.subset_of_source[i] + " ";
      }

      for (var j = 0; j < d.subset_of_target.length; j++) {
        trStr2 += d.subset_of_target[j] + " ";
      }



      info.html("<h3>Link " + "<i>" + d.value + "</i></h3>" +
        "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>Description</button>+" +
        "<div class='content'>" +
        "<ul>" +
        "<li><b>Subset of source: </b>" + trStr1 + "</li>" +
        "<li><b>Subset of target: </b>" + trStr2 + "</li>" +
        "<li><b>Prefix: </b>" + d.prefix + "</li>" +
        "<li><b>Frequency: </b>" + d.stat + "</li>" +
        "<li><b>Uri: </b>" + "<a style='color:#777;'href= '" + d.uri + "' target='_blank'>" + "" + d.uri + "</a></li>" +
        "</ul>" +
        "</div>")

      /*-----------------------------Menu---------------------------------*/
      var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
          }
        });
      }
      /*---------------------------End Menu---------------------------------*/






    }).style("cursor", "pointer");



  //Nodes:
  node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(nodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      // .on("end", dragended)
    )


  node.append("circle") //ellipse 
    /* .attr("cx", -10)
     .attr("cy", -15)
     .attr("rx", function (d, i) {return d.id.length*4.5;})//70
     .attr("ry", 20)
     //.attr("height","30")
     //.attr("width","80")*/
    .attr("r", 10)

    .style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(d.prefix);
    })
    .on('mouseover.tooltip', function(d) {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", .8);

      var trStr = "";

      for (var i = 0; i < d.children_labels.length; i++) {
        trStr += "<tr><td>" + d.children_labels[i].name + "</td></tr>";
      }

      tooltip.html(
          "<table border=1>" +
          "<tr>" + "<th>Label set</th></tr>" +
          trStr +
          "</table>")
        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on('mouseover.fade', fade(0.1))
    .on("mouseout.tooltip", function() {
      tooltip.transition()
        .duration(100)
        .style("opacity", 0);
    })

    .on("mousemove", function() {
      tooltip.style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY + 10) + "px");
    })
    .on('dblclick', releasenode)

    .on("click.info", function(d) {
      info.transition()
        .duration(300)
        .style("opacity", 1);

      var trStr = "";
      var trStr2 = "";
      var trQuery = "";


      for (var i = 0; i < d.children_labels.length; i++) {
        trStr += "<a style='color:#777;'href= '" + d.children_labels[i].uri + "' target='_blank'>" + "" + d.children_labels[i].name + "</a></br>"
        trQuery += "<li><input type = 'hidden' id='endPoint' name='endPoint' value=" + HTMLEncode(d.children_labels[i].endpoint) + ">" + "<p id = 'queryString" + i + "'>" + HTMLEncode(d.children_labels[i].query_String) + "</p>" + "<button id=" + i + " type='button' class='buttonInfo' onclick='query2(" + i + ")'> Execute</button></li>"
      }



      for (var i = 0; i < d.dataproperties.length; i++) {
        trStr2 += "<li>" + d.dataproperties[i].domain + " , " + "<a style='color:#777;'href= '" + d.dataproperties[i].uri + "' target='_blank'>" + "" + d.dataproperties[i].name + "</a>" + " (" + d.dataproperties[i].count + ") , " + d.dataproperties[i].range + "</li>";
        //trStr += d.children_labels[i].name+" ";
      }


      if (d.children_labels.length == 0) {


        SetCookie("queryString", d.query_String);
        SetCookie("endPoint", d.endpoint);



        info.html("<h3> Node " + "<i>" + d.id + "</i></h3>" +
          "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>Description</button>+" +
          "<div class='content'>" +
          "<ul>" +
          "<li><b>Prefix: </b>" + d.prefix + "</li>" +
          "<li><b>Label set: </b>" + trStr + "</li>" +
          "<li><b>Uri: </b>" + "<a style='color:#777;'href= '" + d.uri + "' target='_blank'>" + "" + d.uri + "</a></li>"

          +
          "</ul></div>"

          +
          "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>Data properties</button>+" +
          "<div class='content'>" +
          "<ul>" +
          trStr2 + "</br>" +
          "</ul>" +
          "</div>"

          +
          "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>Query</button>+" +
          "<div class='content'>"

          //+"<input type = 'text' id='queryString' name='queryString' value="+ HTMLEncode(d.query_String) +">"
          +
          "<p>" + HTMLEncode(d.query_String) + "</p>"

          +
          "<button type='button' class='buttonInfo' onclick='query()'>Execute</button>"

          +
          "</div>"


        )


      } else {

        info.html("<h3> Node " + "<i>" + d.id + "</i></h3>" +
          "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>Description</button>+" +
          "<div class='content'>" +
          "<ul>" +
          "<li><b>Prefix: </b>" + d.prefix + "</li>" +
          "<li><b>Label link set: </b></br>" + trStr + "</li>" +
          "</ul></div>"

          +
          "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>Data properties</button>+" +
          "<div class='content'>" +
          "<ul>" +
          trStr2 + "</ul>" +
          "</div>"

          +
          "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>Queries</button>+" +
          "<div class='content'>" +
          "<ul>" +
          trQuery + "</ul>" +
          "</div>"

        )

      }

      // console.log(HTMLEncode(d.query_String));



      /*-----------------------------Menu---------------------------------*/
      var coll = document.getElementsByClassName("collapsible");
      var i;
      for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
          this.classList.toggle("active");
          var content = this.nextElementSibling;
          if (content.style.display === "block") {
            content.style.display = "none";
          } else {
            content.style.display = "block";
          }
        });
      }
      /*---------------------------End Menu---------------------------------*/


    })




  node.append("text")
    .attr("dy", -10) //-10
    .attr("dx", -10) //-15
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d.id
    });




  simulation
    .nodes(nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

  simulation.force("link")
    .links(links);





  //----------------------Fade----------------------
  var linkedByIndex = {};

  links.forEach(function(d) {
    linkedByIndex[d.source.index + "," + d.target.index] = 1;
  });


  // check the dictionary to see if nodes are linked
  function isConnected(a, b) {
    return linkedByIndex[a.index + "," + b.index] || linkedByIndex[b.index + "," + a.index] || a.index == b.index;
  }

  function fade(opacity) {
    return d => {
      node.style('stroke-opacity', function(o) {
        const thisOpacity = isConnected(d, o) ? 1 : opacity;
        this.setAttribute('fill-opacity', thisOpacity);
        return thisOpacity;

        node.text.style("opacity", o => (o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity));
      });



      link.style('opacity', o => (o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity));

      edgelabels.style('opacity', o => (o.source === d || o.target === d ? 1 : opacity));


    };
  }
  //-------------------End fade-------------------


}


//Functions:



function HTMLEncode(html) {
  var temp = document.createElement("div");
  (temp.textContent != null) ? (temp.textContent = html) : (temp.innerText = html);
  var output = temp.innerHTML;
  temp = null;
  return output;
}



function ReadCookie(cookie_name) {
  //Determine if a cookie exists
  if (document.cookie.length > 0) {
    //cookie start part
    cookie_start = document.cookie.indexOf(cookie_name + "=")

    if (cookie_start != -1) {

      cookie_start = cookie_start + cookie_name.length + 1
      cookie_end = document.cookie.indexOf(";", cookie_start)
      //If it is already the last cookie value, take the cookie length
      if (cookie_end == -1) {
        cookie_end = document.cookie.length
      }
      //Get cookie value, unescape to decrypt special characters
      return unescape(document.cookie.substring(cookie_start, cookie_end))
    }
  }

  return ""
}


function SetCookie(cookieName, cookieValue) {
  //set Cookie:
  document.cookie = cookieName + "=" + escape(cookieValue)

}

function query() {
  //   document.location = "Query_Sparql/Res_Query.html";
  window.open("Res_Query.html", "_blank");

}

function query2(i) {
  var endPoint = $("endPoint").value;
  var queryString = $("queryString" + i).innerText; //innerText;

  if (endPoint.length > 0 && endPoint && queryString.length > 0 && queryString) {
    SetCookie("endPoint", endPoint);
    SetCookie("queryString", queryString);

    // document.location = "Query_Sparql/Res_Query.html";
    window.open("Res_Query.html", "_blank");
  }

}


function $(id) {
  return document.getElementById(id);
}




function ticked() {


  //bezier:
  link
    .attr("d", d => {

      if (d.target == d.source) {
        dr = 30 / d.linknum; //30
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 1,1 " + d.target.x + "," + (d.target.y + 1);

      } else if (d.size % 2 != 0 && d.linknum == 1) {
        //return 'M '+d.source.x+' '+d.source.y+' L '+ d.target.x +' '+d.target.y;
        return `
            M 
              ${d.source.x} ${d.source.y} 
            C 
              ${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2} ${d.source.y} 
              ${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2} ${d.target.y} 
              ${d.target.x} ${d.target.y}
          `

      }
      var curve = 1.5;
      var homogeneous = 1.2;
      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * (d.linknum + homogeneous) / (curve * homogeneous);
      if (d.linknum < 0) {
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * (-1 * d.linknum + homogeneous) / (curve * homogeneous);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,0 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
      }
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
    })
    .style('fill', 'none');;




  node
    .attr("transform", function(d) {
      return "translate(" + d.x + ", " + d.y + ")";
    });
  edgepaths
    .attr('d', function(d) {
      //  return 'M ' + d.source.x + ' ' + d.source.y + ' L ' + d.target.x + ' ' + d.target.y;
      if (d.target == d.source) {
        dr = 30 / d.linknum;
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 1,1 " + d.target.x + "," + (d.target.y + 1);
      } else if (d.size % 2 != 0 && d.linknum == 1) {
        return `
            M 
              ${d.source.x} ${d.source.y} 
            C 
              ${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2} ${d.source.y} 
              ${(d.source.x + d.target.x) / 2} ${d.target.y} 
              ${d.target.x} ${d.target.y}
          `
      }

      var curve = 1.5;
      var homogeneous = 2.8;
      var dx = d.target.x - d.source.x,
        dy = d.target.y - d.source.y,
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * (d.linknum + homogeneous) / (curve * homogeneous);

      if (d.linknum < 0) {
        dr = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) * (-1 * d.linknum + homogeneous) / (curve * homogeneous);
        return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,0 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;
      }
      return "M" + d.source.x + "," + d.source.y + "A" + dr + "," + dr + " 0 0,1 " + d.target.x + "," + d.target.y;

    });


  edgelabels.attr('transform', function(d) {
    if (d.target.x < d.source.x) {
      var bbox = this.getBBox();

      rx = bbox.x + bbox.width / 2;
      ry = bbox.y + bbox.height / 2;
      return 'rotate(180 ' + rx + ' ' + ry + ')';
    } else {
      return 'rotate(0)';
    }
  });



}


function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
  //  d3.select(this).classed("fixed", d.fixed = true);

}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
  fix_nodes(d);

}


// Preventing other nodes from moving while dragging one node
function fix_nodes(this_node) {
  node.each(function(d) {
    if (this_node != d) {
      d.fx = d.x;
      d.fy = d.y;
    }
  });
}


function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;

}


function releasenode(d) {
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}







//Grouping links:
function setLinkNumber(group, type) {
  if (group.length == 0) return;
  //The relationships within this group are sorted by direction, in this case into two sections based on the ASCII size of the connected entities
  var linksA = [],
    linksB = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < group.length; i++) {
    var link = group[i];
    if (link.source < link.target) {
      linksA.push(link);
    } else {
      linksB.push(link);
    }
  }
  //Determine the maximum number of relations. In order to make the relationship curve connecting two entities appear symmetrical, the relations are divided equally according to the parity of the number of relations.
  // Special case: when the relations are both connected to the same entity, no equal division
  var maxLinkNumber = 0;
  if (type == 'self') {
    maxLinkNumber = group.length;
  } else {
    maxLinkNumber = group.length % 2 == 0 ? group.length / 2 : (group.length + 1) / 2;
  }
  //If there are as many relationships in both directions, it is straightforward to set the numbers separately
  if (linksA.length == linksB.length) {
    var startLinkNumber = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < linksA.length; i++) {
      linksA[i].linknum = startLinkNumber++;
    }
    startLinkNumber = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < linksB.length; i++) {
      linksB[i].linknum = startLinkNumber++;
    }
  } else { //When the number of relations in the two directions is not equal, the group of relations with the smallest number is numbered in reverse order from the maximum numbering value, then the other group of relations with the largest number is numbered from number 1 to the maximum number, and then the remaining relations are numbered negatively
    // If the negative numbering is left aside, it can be seen that the final numbering sequence of all relations must be symmetrical (the symmetry is to ensure that the curves are also curved symmetrically when plotted subsequently)
    var biggerLinks, smallerLinks;
    if (linksA.length > linksB.length) {
      biggerLinks = linksA;
      smallerLinks = linksB;
    } else {
      biggerLinks = linksB;
      smallerLinks = linksA;
    }

    var startLinkNumber = maxLinkNumber;
    for (var i = 0; i < smallerLinks.length; i++) {
      smallerLinks[i].linknum = startLinkNumber--;
    }
    var tmpNumber = startLinkNumber;

    startLinkNumber = 1;
    var p = 0;
    while (startLinkNumber <= maxLinkNumber) {
      biggerLinks[p++].linknum = startLinkNumber++;
    }
    //Start with negative numbering
    startLinkNumber = 0 - tmpNumber;
    for (var i = p; i < biggerLinks.length; i++) {
      biggerLinks[i].linknum = startLinkNumber++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Add a classes on nodes and links with suffix as colorvalue..node.append("circle") .attr("class", function(d, i) {
      return "node"+color(d.prefix);
    }).style("fill", function(d, i) {
      return color(d.prefix);
    }) . Then on click, select based on d3.select(".node" + colorValue).attr("opacity", 0) and for all others d3.select('node').attr("opactity", 1)

Comment: hi, sorry for the late answer, i tried your solution but it did'nt work also i couln't understand why u used colorValue

Comment: Not colorValue but the color prefix, whatever is associated class with that node. check the classnames on html generated and select based on that